# How do you create a carousel menu interface like in the iPhone using WPF?

Tags: iphone, wpf, menu

I've seen a couple of tutorials, but not with dynamic animation. Could anyone please teach me at least a rough tutorial on it?

I'm a C# developer but have been doing flash animations a long time.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way by far is to buy a 3rd party component that does this from a vendor like Infragistics.

It would be possible and interesting to do in raw WPF but it would not be a quick time to market.

Comment: Basically true... it would be a completely custom control. Looking at Infragistics' XamCarouselPanel source code there's 5000 lines in the main class alone, with maybe 10 supporting classes.